# Nunit, Asp.net MVC 4, Sql Server CE 4, error provider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, sql-server-ce, asp.net-mvc-4

- I created a simple Asp.net MVC 4 application
- I created the NUnit test project using the visula studio 2010 extension
- I add a couple of controllers (with the models and views) and the website works fine. It works with Sql Server CE

Now I need to test a controller. I wrote this simple class:

```
namespace SkateboardShop.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    class BrandControllerTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void TestDetailsView()
        {

            var controller = new BrandController();
            var result = controller.Details(2) as ViewResult;
            Assert.AreEqual("Details", result.ViewName);

        }

    }
}
```

When I run this test the NUnit return me this error:

> SkateboardShop.Tests.Controllers.BrandControllerTest.TestDetailsView:
>   System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException : An error occurred while
>   getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by
>   Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct.   ----> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException : The
>   provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.   ---->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Sure, where the test project get the data provider information?
I add into the app.config file (of the test project) the connection string like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SkateboardEntities" connectionString="Data Source=d:\Basic\project\asp\SkateboardShop\SkateboardShop\App_Data\SkateboardShop.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But nothing to do.
Since I'm new in MVC and NUnit, I'm asking, in the first place, if the Unit Test should test real database data and if it's a good way, how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these integration tests? If so, then does your test project contain a config file similar to your asp.net app? If it's not an integration test, then you have failed to inject the dependency for your persistence layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion - you should be having a mock repository/persistance layer for testing.
In that way - you can have a predictable result set to work against & write tests to.

An example of this could be your controllers accepting an instance of a repository with code like:

```
public class BrandController{
 public BrandController(IBrandRepository repository){...}
}
```

You can use any DI + Mock framework to inject the IBrandRepository for unit testing

But, there are situations where the mock is not sufficient & you do need a physical database for testing.

In such cases, I would recommend to have a test database which has the same structure, but test data which can be re-seeded/initialized as needed for your unit testing.

In this case, you could point your config file to the test database for testing & some sort of script or DbInitializer to initialize the database back to the original state etc.

HTH.

Comment: If someone need an example of it, here I found a project where to see how to restructure the application: http://efmvc.codeplex.com/